# Compare two dataframes and add values from another column where rows matched

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have two dataframes `DB` and `compareDF`. I'm trying to compare and match these two dataframes at same value `phone_number`, which works, but after the row matching I would like to add `customer_code` (another column) from `DB` to `compareDF['cmp2']` where the value is matched, which doesn't works (It does not add customer_code from matched row but instead it adds values from customer_code one after another from the start of `DB`)

```py
m1 = compareDF['phone_number'].isin(DB['phone_number'])
compareDF['cmp2'] = DB['customer_code'].where(m1)
```

I have these

```
# DB

0 phone_number  customer_code
1     055            1
2     077            2
3     088            3
```

```
# compareDF

0 phone_number     cmp2
1     077            
2     088            
3     055
```

I want this

```
# compareDF

0 phone_number     cmp2
1     077            2 
2     088            3
3     055            1
```

I'm getting this

```
# compareDF

0 phone_number     cmp2
1     077            1 
2     088            2
3     055            3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and join the two data sets on the `phone_number` key. The `compareDF` should be the primary table in this join as well.

```
df1.merge(df, how="inner", on="phone_number").rename(columns={"customer_code": "cmp2"})

# where

df = pd.DataFrame({"phone_number": ["055", "077", "088"], "customer_code": [1, 2, 3]})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"phone_number": ["077", "088", "055"]})

# gives

  phone_number  cmp2
0          077     2
1          088     3
2          055     1
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done directly with merge,and you can modify the name of the column by df.columns = [xxx]：

```
res = pd.merge(db, compareDF)
res.columns = ["phone_number", "cmp2"]
print(res)
```